# Отследить загрузку iframe

Tags: jquery

Меняю у `iframe` `src` с помощью jQuery, хотелось бы чтобы пока загружается содержимое `src`, поверх самого `iframe` был фон загрузки.

Как можно добавить стиль на время загрузки `iframe`?

Comment: Добавить стиль на время загрузки не проблема. Сначала добавили стиль, а потом уже поменяли src у iframe. Правильно ли я понимаю, что основная проблема понять когда документ в iframe загрузился полностью и в этот момент убрать стиль загрузки?

Comment: да именно так и нужно

Answer (score 1):

Итак, у нас есть такой код:

```
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
```

Listener на событие вешается до того, как это событие может произойти (именно по этому я не указал атрибут `src`).

Например, приведенный в одном из ответов код:

```
<div class="iframe-container">
   <div class="on-load-iframe-bg"></div>
   <iframe class="my-iframe" src="you_url"></iframe>
</div>

$('.my-iframe').on('load', function(){
   $(this).closest('.iframe-container').find('.on-load-iframe-bg').remove();
});
```

Может или сработать или нет. Событие загрузки может сработать раньше, чем вы начнете слушать это событие. Чтобы избежать таких случаев, значение атрибута `src` добавляется после того, когда был добавлен нужный listener.

В итоге, нужен примерно такой скрипт:

```
<script>
    var iframe = document.querySelector('#iframe');

    // Добавляем listener
    iframe.addEventListener('load', function () {
        alert('ok');
    });

    // Загружаем что-то
    iframe.setAttribute('src', '//###');
</script>
```

Если вам нужно поймать `DOMContentLoaded` внутри `<iframe>`, тогда стоит поискать что-нибудь по ключам `iframe contentWindow` и `iframe contentDocument`

Comment: Ну если уж на то пошло, то использование alert это как плохой тон и лучше заменить его на console.log('ok')

Comment: Это не принципиально в данном контексте.

Comment: Но насчет атрибута согласен добавить стоит его

Answer (score 0):

```
$('iframe').on('load', function(){
   $(this).removeClass('myClassBg');
});
```

Как-то так должно по идеи работать.

Проверил работает все ок. (FireFox & Chrome)

Но я бы советовал делать так.

```
.iframe-container {position: relative;}
.on-load-iframe-bg {position: absolute;}


<div class="iframe-container">
   <div class="on-load-iframe-bg"></div>
   <iframe class="my-iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

Так вот будет более правильно:

```
(function(){
    var $myIframe;

    $(function(){
        $myIframe = $('.my-iframe');
        $myIframe.on('load', function(){
            $(this).closest('.iframe-container').find('.on-load-iframe-bg').remove();
        });
        $myIframe.attr('src', 'you_url');
    });
})();
```